# Different calculation of timestamp from two string date formats in python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, python-datetime, date-formatting

I need to read two date in string type but in different format and so I need them to be well interpreted. My problem is that I don't understand why when I add days or month or year to the date in the exemple, then the values of the timestamps of the two date stay the same. But if I change the hour, or I remove a single day or a month to this date (the one in the exemple) then the out put timestamps are different.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

string_date1 = '2004-03-29-0_0_0'
other_string_date2 = '2004-03-29T00:00:0.0+02:00'

datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date1, "%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S")
timestamp_date1 = int(datetime_obj.timestamp()) - int(pd.Timestamp("2004-01-01").timestamp()) #time in timestamp since 2004

timestamp_date2 = int(pd.to_datetime(other_string_date2 ).timestamp())-int(pd.Timestamp("2004-01-01").timestamp())

print(timestamp_date1)
print(timestamp_date2)
```

I've tried various function like `datetime.datetime.strptime(other_string_date2 , "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")`, but I can't find the format that match to the string : `'2004-03-29T00:00:0.0+02:00'`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You have some form of string that contains a date, and you want to identify the date format. But what the calculation go to do with that? Rather, what's the purpose of your calculation?

Comment: the purpose is to stock the timestamp in a protobuf message in order to have a more compressed format of a date and I do the substraction of the timestamp of 2004 because it make it shorter rather than the one done by pandas or datetime that is a timestamps since 1970. I have various sources that I have to convert to protobuf messages so I need a robust function for the timestamp calculation. Making test with this I saw this strange behavior.

Comment: It's still unclear to me what the actual question is. For parsing directives, [see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). In general, `.timestamp()` gives you Unix time, as a floating point number. If you subtract some number from that, that doesn't reduce the amount of *data* (bytes) needed to represent that value. It only makes things complicated for anyone other than you trying to make sense of those values.

Comment: Moreover, note that date/time represented by strings `string_date1` and `other_string_date2` aren't directly comparable since one has a UTC offset (+02:00) while the other does not. You'll have to make *assumptions* about the date/time without UTC offset, e.g. that it's local time or UTC.

Comment: @Thefoxsay you might want to put the comments (purpose) in your code lines, specially with your date conversions. As FObersteiner said, why don't you use one conversion date format to clean up all your various date formats like strings?

Comment: I think I found the problem, it comes from the `other_string_date2` like it has a UTC, it tkae in consideration if we are in winter hour or in summer hour. It looks like the reference for the `string_date1` is the summer hour. But I don't know how to ignore this change in the case of `other_string_date2`
To anwer you i've tried to use the `datetime.strptime()` function but I'm not able to make it work with the  `other_string_date2`